# How to find amount changed given rate of increase

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

**Question**

Let $w'(t)=t-4$ the rate per month which Math Dragon grows in weight, if his initial weight was 2.718 tons, what was his weight after 1 year after when he was born?

I wasn't really sure what to do and I think that I'm supposed to do $\int_0^1w'(t)$ but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Since $w'(t)$ is in months, your boundaries of integration must also be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a unit problem because the units of weight change are per month, not per year.  You are not given the weight unit for $w'$ so I would assume $w'$ is in tons per month.  Your basic idea to integrate the weight change is a good one but you need to adjust the upper limit.  I'm not sure what to make of the fact that the weight is negative at $t=2$ and for a region around it.